# HTML Tags containing Vue.js v-if and v-for directives flash at loading

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I use Vue.js to send data to a basic and very simple API that subscribes an e-mail address to a newsletter *via* the form below and to display some messages (state and errors).

I use in particularly the directives v-if and v-for to display the errors and two messages. The thing is when the page is loading, those two paragraph elements and the unordered list element "flash" until the page is fully loaded or until the Vue.js instance is mounted.

Am I doing it wrong? Is this a common issue? Is there anything I can do to prevent all those elements to flash at loading ?

Thank you in advance.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="subscribe-to-newsletter">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="storeSubscriber" novalidate>
        <label for="email-address">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email-address" placeholder="exemple@nomdedomaine.fr" v-model="emailAddress">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Rester informé">
    </form>

    <p v-if="success">Thank you, we will keep you updated</p>

    <p v-if="loading">Loading</p>

    <ul v-for="error in errors.email_address">
        <li v-text="error"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
const subscribe = new Vue({
    el: '#subscribe-to-newsletter',

    data: {
        emailAddress: '',
        loading: false,
        success: false,
        errors: []
    },

    methods: {
        storeSubscriber() {
            subscribe.success = false;
            subscribe.errors = [];
            subscribe.loading = true;

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/api/subscriber', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    subscribe.loading = false;

                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        subscribe.success = true;
                    } else {
                        subscribe.errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.send(encodeURI('email_address=' + subscribe.emailAddress));
        },
    }
})
```

**Edit**

<s>I tried to use the v-cloak directive and it is not solving the problem.</s>

[JSFiddle of the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/er7exmm5/)

**Solution**

Add this in your CSS

```
[v-cloak] {
    display: none;
}
```

And here's the new HTML:

```
<div id="subscribe-to-newsletter">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="storeSubscriber" novalidate>
        <label for="email-address">E-mail address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email_address" id="email-address" placeholder="exemple@nomdedomaine.fr" v-model="emailAddress">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Rester informé">
    </form>

    <p v-if="success" v-cloak>Thank you, we will keep you updated</p>

    <p v-if="loading" v-cloak>Loading</p>

    <ul v-for="error in errors.email_address" v-cloak>
        <li v-text="error"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use promises.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **v-cloak** and it will solve it.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this one (sorry I forgot to precise it), I just tried again and it is not working.

Comment: try to create JS Fiddle.

Comment: I misread the documentation. The use of `v-cloak`does work. Thank you!

Comment: Done. I need 15 reputation though. Then you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you variable: `loading` be true in the beginning:

```
data: {
    emailAddress: '',
    loading: true,
    success: false,
    errors: []
},
```

Comment: No it is loading only when the user clicks the `<input type="submit">`. Sorry I forgot a line in the `storeSubscriber()` method.