# Vue.js showing content that should be hidden by a v-if tag when user refreshes page

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue.js app that loads content in the `created()` method. I use a `v-if` tag to hide all of my UI until that content is loaded and ready to go. It works fine on the initial load, but if a user were to hit refresh in Chrome then the app displays (flashes momentarily) content that would not otherwise be displayed (based on the data being loaded in created).

From what I understand using the `v-if` tag, with a flag from my vuex store that indicates when the load has completed, is the proper way to hide content until I am ready to display it.

How can I avoid having the content flash on the refresh?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870926/v-cloak-does-not-work-in-vue-js

Comment: Solved here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847096/html-tags-containing-vue-js-v-if-and-v-for-directives-flash-at-loading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue.JS has solved this using the `v-cloak` directive. ([see docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak))

You add the `v-cloak` directive to your application's root element:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
...
</div>
```

Then add this CSS rule to your application's stylesheet:

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

Everything within the `app` div will then be hidden until Vue has initialized.

Comment: Still good in Vue 3 - https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-cloak